# window.rootViewController nil while unwrapping

Tags: swift, coordinator-layout, coordinator-pattern

I want to use Coordinator in my Swift project by using the file `Navigator()`, but I need to pass a `UINavigationController` inside to `navigator.show()`.

The problem is that XCode shows this error:

```
Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in window!
```

AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow!
  let navigator = Navigator()

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let feedNavigation = window!.rootViewController!  as! UINavigationController
    navigator.show(segue: .listBeer, sender: feedNavigation)
    
    return true
  }
}
```

How can I pass this `window.rootViewController! as! UINavigationController`  as a non-Optional value?

Comment: Have in your project SceneDelegate class file?

Comment: yes! but is not altered.

Comment: Try this : UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

Comment: Nice!! This woks! Thank you!!!

Comment: @ianp: see here for more info on your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu